# I cannot access to user points pages: myuserpoints/ID

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, userpoints

I'm using the "User Points" module in Drupal to assign points to the users given the rating on some of their nodes.

I visited the menu: admin/user/userpoints from which I can see users scores.

However when I click on one of them, I get "Access Denied" (and I'm the admin id=1).

For example, this link is forbidden for me:

```
myuserpoints/6
```

I can only visit my own:

```
myuserpoints/1
```

But if the module does provide a list with all user points, I guess i'm supposed to see them.. or not ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/362119), it seems there is a patch for the problem. Try if that fixes it for you.

User 1 should never see an access denied message, that is definitely a bug.

Comment: The issue report has been marked as fixed (and then automatically closed); that means the fix has been already implemented in a release of the module (official release or development snapshot).

Comment: It should be in the dev release, but not in the stable one.